# Nginx beginner - What will be the regexp for accessing /<path>

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Below is my nginx.conf file which is working , that is when I hit tester.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com in my VPC i am able to route my request to github.com , but I want to make my tester.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/github point to github.com more importantly. I tried fiddling around with the conf file but was not able to succeed. Can someone help.

```
    listen       80;
    server_name  tester.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com;

    location / {
                   proxy_pass              https://github.com;
                   proxy_redirect          http://tester.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/ https://github.com;   
               }

     location = /40x.html {
                }
```

Comment: do you want to redirect to githubhub.com ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try the below configs?

```
 location /github {
   proxy_pass     https://github.com;
   proxy_redirect http://tester.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/github https://github.com;   
}
```

Comment: yes I tried the above and had no luck as it is going to https://github.com/github and fails.

Comment: and you want it to go only to  github.com ? if that is the case just update the redirect line as in the above snippet